# Simplify Makefile and maybe avoid using $(basename $@) is multiple places

Tags: makefile

I am new to Makefiles and it works as expected. But I am wondering is there a way to simplify this Makefile I wrote. More specifically I used `$(basename $@).scala` and `$(basename $@)` in many places and I think it is an anti-pattern. Or maybe is there a way to generalize it.

I appreciate any feedback or hint.

```
SPECS=First Follow
EXAMPLES_PATH=../..
ROOT_PATH=../${EXAMPLES_PATH}
SCALAV=2.12
APSLIB=${ROOT_PATH}/lib/aps-library-${SCALAV}.jar
SCALA_FLAGS=.:${APSLIB}
APS2SCALA=${ROOT_PATH}/bin/aps2scala

all: $(addsuffix Spec.compile, $(SPECS)) $(addsuffix Spec.run, $(SPECS))

%.generate:
    ${APS2SCALA} -DCOT -p ${EXAMPLES_PATH}:${ROOT_PATH}/base $*

%.run:
    @scala -cp ${SCALA_FLAGS} $(basename $@)

GrammarUtil.compile: grammar.generate
    scalac -cp ${SCALA_FLAGS} grammar.scala $(basename $@).scala

first.compile:
    scalac -cp ${SCALA_FLAGS} $(basename $@).scala

follow.compile:
    scalac -cp ${SCALA_FLAGS} $(basename $@).scala

Spec.compile:
    scalac -cp ${SCALA_FLAGS} $(basename $@).scala

FirstSpec.compile: Spec.compile grammar.generate GrammarUtil.compile first.generate first.compile
    scalac -cp ${SCALA_FLAGS} $(basename $@).scala

FollowSpec.compile: Spec.compile grammar.generate GrammarUtil.compile follow.generate follow.compile
    scalac -cp ${SCALA_FLAGS} $(basename $@).scala

clean:
    rm -f *.class grammar.scala first.scala follow.scala
```

Comment: You are already using `$*` in some places. Does this not do exactly what you are asking? Just refactor to a single `%.compile` rule, which also does away with unattractive code duplication.

Comment: @tripleee I am trying to fix it but now I get an error: https://gist.github.com/amir734jj/645a94412475dfb700f6116dd1c7e1bc  "make: *** No rule to make target 'grammar.aps'.  Stop"

Answer (score 0):

The Make variable `$*` does roughly this; it returns whatever matched `%` in a pattern rule (called the stem).

Several of your recipes have exactly the same code, so there are multiple reasons to refactor to use a pattern rule instead. A complication as that one of the `*.compile` rules has a second dependency, but we can simply create a rule which leaves this part empty if there is only one dependency.

```
%.compile: %.scala
    scalac -cp ${SCALA_FLAGS} $(filter-out $<,$^) $<
grammar.compile: grammar.generate
```

This also fixes the bug that it declares the formerly undeclared (but obvious) dependency on the `%.scala` file; thus, we use `$<` instead of `$*.scala` though in this case they are basically equivalent.

`$(filter-out $<,$^)` removes the first dependency (`%.scala`) from the list of all depencencies, yielding either nothing or `grammar.generate`.

However, your Makefile still appears to have several other undeclared dependencies, and inconsistent naming for some targets.

In particular, the above requires you to rename `GrammarUtil` to `grammar`; without more information about your inputs and their internal dependencies, I can't tell if that's really feasible.

Probably a less rocky road would be to keep exactly the same stem for all related files, and accept the default output file name (I'm guessing `%.o`? But I'm not familiar with Scala) instead of made-up and probably nonexistent pseudo-filenames like `%.compile`. (If you want to keep these, and they indeed do not correspond to actual file names, you should probably declare them as `.PHONY`; but then you are disabling useful and important `make` functionality.)